# Heroku run rake db:migrate error rake command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, migration

I'm running the run rake db:migration command and terminal is telling me that rake is not a command

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app"glacial-lake-5597"
Running `rake db:migrate --appglacial-lake-5597` attached to terminal... up, run.1930
bash: rake: command not found

$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4588
bash: rake: command not found
```

i've already bundle installed and committed changes to git.

I've looked all over StackOverflow and I cannot find the answer

Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Are you sure there's no typos in the command? There should be a space between the `--app` option and the name of the application, as in `heroku run rake db:migrate --app "glacial-lake-5597"`

Comment: check if your app deployed correctly with no errors

Comment: eugen I just retried with the space in the -app option and still no luck.
very new to the rails environment. @Sontya how do i check if the app deployed correctly? Heroku open opens to a webpage that just says welcome so I believe it deployed

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem,

The cause was that I hadn't specified a remote branch when first pushing to Heroku, Heroku apps start with a blank repository – they have no branches and no code. So the first time you deploy, you need to specify a remote branch.

`git push heroku master`

I hadn't done this initially and in doing so this fixed my rake problem.

Answer (score 1):

See if the gem sqlite is in development only.

like this

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To check to see if your app deployed correctly just look at the trace in your shell after you attempt to push to Heroku. I had been running mine in Cloud 9 and not really looking at the results because they were so small, I'm new to this, and, heck, it had always deployed perfectly before....

When I scrolled through I found two errors mentioned; I corrected these errors, then the heroku db migration ran fine. One error was a missing line of code, the other I found on SO (which I can't refind the link to, sorry), and it had to do with the file extensions for my css files, which I changed from .css to .css.scss.